# Why using state setter callback as ref callback does not cause a re-render?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [element, setElement] = React.useState(null);
  const [count, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
  console.log(element);
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    setCounter(count + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1
        ref={setElement}
      >
        Hello CodeSandbox
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
ref={setElement}
```

should cause an infinite loop, however, it prints element once. Why is that happening ?
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-moore-n57m04?file=/src/App.js:0-706)

Answer (score 0):

This is because ref initialization only happens on the first render only!

Comment: This is true https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-waterfall-e4g9en